# simple diff question

Tags: diff

file1.txt is

- 10
- 20
- 30
- 40
- 50

file2.txt is

- 10
- 20
- 40
- 60
- 70
- 80

I want output.txt to be a union of numbers in these two files but with no duplicates.
Output.txt should be

- 10
- 20
- 30
- 40
- 50
- 60
- 70
- 80

Comment: This isn't a diff problem at all. You just want to compute the "set union" ("set" implies no duplicates).

Comment: 1) Is this homework? 2) Are you asking for an existing program that does this, or how to write a program that does this? If the second, what language?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to preserve the order within the individual files:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq > output.txt
```